# More information from PHP error_reporting

Tags: php, error-reporting

I have automated my `error_reporting` process. Errors are logged to a file and periodically sent via email.

Problem is I don't get enough information. E.g. I can see a **undefined index notice**; but I can't see where it was triggered as often its an included file.

Is it possible to get a dump of `$_SERVER` in the error log?

Comment: Have you tried it before posting the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is to catch errors using [this](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.set-error-handler.php)
then log my custom error using [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php)

Comment: Thx, that looks like a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use function [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.debug-backtrace.php)

Function return backtrace for current position.

For Include `$_SERVER` to  email you can use `print_r($_SERVER, true);` but I think this can help you little.